# Django admin panel with filter_horizontal

Tags: python, django, admin

I have 2 tables: `users: id, name` and `user_follow: id, user_id, follow_user_id`

```
#model.py
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    follow = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, related_name = 'followed', verbose_name='followed')
    class Meta:
        managed = True

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s, id=%s" % (self.name, self.id)

class Follow(models.Model):
    '''Describes follow relation between Man instances: who follows whom'''
    who = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='who')
    whom = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='whom')

#admin
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'len_follows', 'len_followed_by')
    list_display_links = ('name',)
    inlines = [FollowsInline, FollowedInline]

    filter_horizontal = ['follow']
```

I need to add one more filter_horizontal to show users who follow this user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thx all I find answer here, this snipet helps me a lot https://snipt.net/chrisdpratt/symmetrical-manytomany-filter-horizontal-in-django-admin/

```
#admin
class UserAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
        followers = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            label="Followers", queryset=Users.objects.all(),
            initial=user.followers.all(),
            widget=admin.widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple("followers", False),
            required=False
        )

        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ("name", "follow", "followers")

        def save(self, commit=True):
            instance = super(UserAdminForm, self).save(commit)
            instance.followers = self.cleaned_data.get("followers", [])
            return instance

    return UserAdminForm

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name", "follow_count", "followers_count")
    filter_horizontal = ("follow",)


    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if obj is not None:
            self.form = make_user_admin_form(obj)
        return super(UserAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```